# dygraph error - this.rawData_ is undefined

Tags: java, jquery, dygraphs

I am using dygraph to generate graph using csv file and getting below error at firebug.

TypeError: this.rawData_ is undefined

I investigated the issue and found that csv is not being loaded entirely and label formatting is being done. Hence I have used drawCallback.

```
graph_obj_2 = new Dygraph(
            document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
             "http://localhost:8080/report_2.csv", // path to CSV file
            {
            //options
            legend: 'always',
            animatedZooms: true,
            drawCallback: function(g, is_initial) {
                            if (!is_initial) {
                                    return;}
                            },
            axes: {
                x: {
                valueFormatter: function(x) {
                var label;
                switch (x){
                    case 1: 
                    label = '0';
                    break;          
                    case 2: 
                    label = '1';
                    break;          
                    case 3: 
                    label = '2';
                    break;          
                    case 4: 
                    label = '3';
                    break;
                }return label;
                },
                axisLabelFormatter: function(x) {
                var label;
                switch (x){
                    case 1: 
                    label = '0';
                    break;          
                    case 2: 
                    label = '1';
                    break;          
                    case 3: 
                    label = '2';
                    break;          
                    case 4: 
                    label = '3';
                    break;
                }return label;
                },
            }
            }
        });
```

Please help me to fix this error. Please note that you will get this error only if you are using csv file(not inline data) and labels of your choice.

Please consider that all parentheses has been closed properly.

Comment: Are you sure the request for the CSV file is succeeding? What do the contents of the CSV file look like? I don't follow what you mean about the drawCallback -- as written, it does nothing.

Comment: yes csv file is getting downloaded properly.